# SimpleCrypt Python Error

Tags: python, encryption

I am using the [`simplecrypt` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-crypt) to encrypt a file, however I cannot seem to read the file in a way that `simplecrypt` can decode it.

Encryption code:

```
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt
def encrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        plaintext = fo.read()
    enc = encrypt(plaintext, key)
    with open(file_name + ".enc", 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(enc)

encrypt_file("test.txt", "securepass")
```

This works fine and runs without any errors, however as soon as i try to decode it i get this error (using the below code)

`simplecrypt.DecryptionException: Data to decrypt must be bytes; you cannot use a string because no string encoding will accept all possible characters.`

```
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt
def decrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key)
    with open(file_name[:-4], 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(dec)
decrypt_file("test.txt.enc", "securepass")
```

Comment: Could you take a look to the indentation? It looks like the `encrypt_file` and `decrypt_file` functions are unindented?

Comment: Sorry about that, the code did not translate into stack overflow very well. The indentation is fine (the encrypt works fine, and decrypt works till the error is thrown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha... Minor mistake **:-)**

According to the docs in [the link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-crypt) you provided in your question, the arguments to `symplecrypt.encrypt` and `simplecrypt.decrypt` are `('password', text)`. In your code you've got that inverted ( `(text, key)` ). You're passing the text to encrypt/decrypt in the first argument and the key in the second. Just reverse that order and will work.

Working example:

```
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt
def encrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        plaintext = fo.read()
    print "Text to encrypt: %s" % plaintext
    enc = encrypt(key, plaintext)
    with open(file_name + ".enc", 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(enc)

def decrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = decrypt(key, ciphertext)
    print "decrypted text: %s" % dec
    with open(file_name[:-4], 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(dec)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    encrypt_file("test.txt", "securepass")
    decrypt_file("test.txt.enc", "securepass")
```