# Simplecrypt: Data to decrypt must be bytes

Tags: python, encryption

So, I wrote encrypted data to txt file.
And I read the line using `readline()`.
But what I get is string type value.

In the text file, it looks like this:

```
`b'sc\x00\x01\x9eU\x86\x8aV\x8f\xa3\x9f\xf4iD\x9bv\xea\x05\x11\xdeo\xd7 \xef\xb1iK\xc1;\xa5\x02\x9fz@\xe4|\x9b^\xe5\xf9e\xc4\xf30\xaa\xe8\xcc>\xf8a\xfa;"\xfb)\xc7z|\xc9\x9c\x1c\x19\xc1}\x15\xdd_\xfd\x90z\x865\xe9O\xef\xd9\t\x06\x9c'`

(b'~~~~~~')
```

But, when I read the text file in python and put it in the variable, it looks like this:

```
'b\'sc\\x00\\x01\\x9eU\\x86\\x8aV\\x8f\\xa3\\x9f\\xf4iD\\x9bv\\xea\\x05\\x11\\xdeo\\xd7 \\xef\\xb1iK\\xc1;\\xa5\\x02\\x9fz@\\xe4|\\x9b^\\xe5\\xf9e\\xc4\\xf30\\xaa\\xe8\\xcc>\\xf8a\\xfa;"\\xfb)\\xc7z|\\xc9\\x9c\\x1c\\x19\\xc1}\\x15\\xdd_\\xfd\\x90z\\x865\\xe9O\\xef\\xd9\\t\\x06\\x9c\'\n'
('b\'~~~~~~\'\n')
```

Because of that difference, I get an error message:

```
you cannot use a string because no string encoding will accept all possible characters.
```

It recognizes that as a string.
How do I read from file and put it in the variable in bytes type?

Comment: The text file is ”wrong” IMHO. It seems you've saved the `repr()` form of a `bytes` object into a text file and are now trying to parse that representation back into a `bytes` object. I would save a more common representation of binary data in the text file, for example Base64. Have a look at the `binascii` module in the Python standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be in the data type. Your data is binary data, and it may contain a newline (`\n`). In that case `readline` only reads up to the newline, i.e. only part of the string.

The error message refers to this problem. Unfortunately, `readline` is not reliable with binary data. You will need to encode the binary data into a string (using, e.g. `base64`) so that it can be saved in a text file.

For a working example, see: [SimpleCrypt Python Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264874/simplecrypt-python-error)

For an eaxmple of encoding binary data into a string, see: [How does one encode and decode a string with Python for use in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875771/how-does-one-encode-and-decode-a-string-with-python-for-use-in-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

What I've been doing is using `.decode()` when saving a file, and `.encode()` when loading it, so the text is in the file as a string, and you open it, and read it as bytes.

> Edit:
>
> When encrypting:
>   `with open("encrypted.txt", "w+") as file:
>       file.write(encryptedData.decode())`
>
> When decrypting:
>   `with open("encrypted.txt", "r") as file:
>       encryptedFile = file.readlines()
>       encryptedFile = [line.encode() for line in encryptedFile]`

Comment: Code sample would be nice. Currently your answer seems to be poor